# Options for unit testing a return type I can't easily create

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I need to unit test a method that returns a type I can't easily fake or instantiate.  The type implements `IQueryable<T>` which I originally thought I could use to my advantage, but I don't see how at this point.

For example:

```
public sealed class MyTrickyClass<T> : IQueryable<T>
{
    ...
}

public MyTrickyClass<T> GetData()
{
    return repository.GetAllData();
}
```

and my unit test

```
[Test Method]
public void CanGetData()
{
    var data = (new List<Record>() { new Record() }).AsQueryable();
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IRepository<Record>>();
    mockRepository.Setup(s => s.GetAllData()).Returns(data);

    MyService service = new MyService(mockRepository.Object);
    var result = service.GetData();

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);

}
```

This won't compile because the return type of GetAllData() is `MyTrickyClass<T>`.  If I try to cast `data` to a `MyTrickyClass<Record>` type, the cast fails.

All this makes sense, but it leaves me wondering what the right solution is.  What are some workarounds for this kind of situation?  I may be able to change the MyTrickyClass, but ideally I'd like to find a solution that leaves it alone.

Comment: I guess MyService equals MyTrickyClass?

Comment: No, `MyService` is the class that has the method I want to test, `GetData`.  The `GetAllData()` method that is called within that method returns the `MyTrickyClass` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have `MyTrickyClass<T>` implement interface `ITrickyClass<T>`, which inherits from `IQueryable<T>`.  That seems minimally invasive to your class itself, and you'd have a good seam for mocking.

Comment: You still won't be able to cast an `IQueryable<T>` made from a list to an `ITrickyClass<T>` successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` variable in the test is an `IQueryable<Record>`, not a `MyTrickyClass<Record>`.

Here are some possibilities for fixing it:

- Change `data` in the test to be a `MyTrickyClass<Record>` (though I'm guessing if this was possible you'd already have done it)
- Make `MyTrickyClass` easier to construct, then do the above
- Change the interface of `IRepository` so that it returns an `IQueryable` instead of a  `MyTrickyClass` (which is best if all it needs is the `IQueryable` anyway)
- Wrap the repository in a layer which lets you also wrap the return value. It's another layer of abstraction, but if you find you can't change the repository or `MyTrickyClass` then you probably want to be isolating yourself from it anyway
- As @Erik Dietrich suggested, you could make MyTrickyClass implement an interface. However, you still won't be able to create data using an `IQueryable` as the cast will fail. You could create a mock of `ITrickyClass` instead, though, or create a little stub class that implements the interface (if `MyTrickyClass` is a domain object, you'll probably be using it in a lot of places anyway, so a hand-coded stub may be more useful).